# Email form success in Javascript But no email is being sent with the form data.

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The form seems to validate and go to the confirmation url.  Where I am running into a problem is that the form doesn't send the form data to my email.  I am rather weak in JS and hoping some of your experts can help me with this code.  The link to the page in the website is: http://www.thenaturalcottage.com/ContactUs.html.

The file for the text/javascript file is http://www.thenaturalcottage.com/contact.js
I kept formatting the code to fit here but the code kept throwing an error.

#### Contact Information

Name

Address

City*, State*, Zip*

```
    <p>Telephone<span class="red">*</span></p>
    <p>(<input type="text" name="area" size="3" maxlength="3" onchange="return checkForNumber(this.value);" />
    <input type="text" name="exchange" size="3" maxlength="3" onchange="return checkForNumber(this.value);" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" size="4" maxlength="4" onchange="return checkForNumber(this.value);"  /></p>
    <p>E-mail address<span class="red">*</span><br />
    <input type="text" name="email" size="50" value="Enter your email address" onclick="if(this.value=='Enter your email address') this.value='';" / ></p>
    <p><strong>How do you perfer us to contact you</strong><br />        
    <input type="radio" name="contact" value="Phone" />Phone<br />
    <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email" />Email <br />
    <input type="radio" name="contact" value="mail" />Snail mail
    </p>
    <p>Which one of our services are you interested in recieving information about?</p>
<p>
   <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="classes" /> Classes <br />
   <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="events" /> Events <br />
   <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="customfragarance" /> CustomFragrance    <br />
   <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="suggestions" /> Suggestions<br />
   <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="other" /> Other
   </p>
   <h5>Please enter any comments here:</h5>
   <textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="40">
   </textarea>

   <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
   <p><input type="reset" value="Start Over" /></p>
</form>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
function checkForNumber(fieldValue) {
   //validation for phone number
   var numberCheck = isNaN(fieldValue);
   if(numberCheck == true) {  
       window.alert("You must enter a numeric value!");
       }
}

function confirmSubmit(){
       //confirm submit
       var submitForm = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?");
       //check to make sure that none of the text areas are blank
       if (document.forms[0].name.value == "" || document.forms[0].address.value == "" || document.forms[0].city.value == ""
                             || document.forms[0].state.value == "" || document.forms[0].zip.value == ""){
                             window.alert("You must enter your contact information.");
                             return false;
                             }
        //phone validation
        else if (document.forms[0].area.value == "" || document.forms[0].exchange.value == "" || document.forms[0].phone.value == "") {
                             window.alert("You must enter your telephone number.");
                             return false;
                             }
        //email error message
        else if (document.forms[0].email.value == ""){
                             window.alert("You must enter a correct email address");
                             return false;
                             }
       onsubmit="return confirmSubmit();"
}

function confirmReset(){
       var resetForm = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to reset the form?")
       if (resetForm == true)
       return true;
       return false;                     
       }

function submitForm(){
       if (document.forms[0].firstName.value == "" || document.forms[0].lastName.value == ""){
       window.alert("You must enter your first and last name!");
       return false;
       }
       else 
       return true;       
}

function contactMe(){
       for(var i=0; i<document.forms[0].delivery.length; ++i)
       {
       if (document.forms[0].delivery[i].checked == true)
       document.forms[0].delivery[i].checked = false;
       }
}
```

Comment: You should post your code in the question

Comment: JavaScript cannot send email - the form data has to be passed to a script on your server.  The problem won't be in your HTML or JavaScript - there has to be something wrong with your code that sends the email from your web server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send mail with PHP.

Change `onsubmit="return confirmSubmit();"` on the confirmSubmit with `document.getElementById("form").submit();` and add id to form live `<form id="form" ...`

Add this JS and id's to your fields so the JS can get the values:

```
function mail() {
    var req = new Request({
        method: 'get',  
        url: 'mail.php',
        data: {
       'name':document.getElementById("name").value,
       'adress':document.getElementById("adress").value,
       'city':document.getElementById("city").value
    },
    }).send();
}
```

AND make a PHP file called `mail.php` with:

```
<?php 
//Email Validation
$email = $_GET["email"];
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
//    echo "Your email is ok.".'<br />';
} else {
echo "Wrong email address format.".'<br />'; die();                     
} 

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
// sending email via PHP's Mail()
$to      = $email;
$subject = 'Contact mail subject';
$message = "Name: '.($_GET["name"]).'<br />
            Adress '.($_GET["adress"]).'
            ETC...........";
$headers = 'From: cherie@thenaturalcottage.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: you@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

It is thought strongly recomended you use validation for your input fields AND a mail lybrary instead of simple and vulnerable PHP mail.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what about javascript and nodejs?

Comment: @Four_lo welcome to edit, or add another answer! this is my contribute to put her in the right track, but there is always a better way in coding :)

Comment: honestly just wondering, about to try my hand at nodejs emailers and have no idea what i am doing and information is not as available in this topic as others I have tackled

Comment: Afraid that Dreamweaver is not liking this code and I don't know PHP at all to fix it:
$headers = 'From: sofie@sofiesrenting.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: cherie@thenaturalcottage.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
?>

Comment: Hi, changed the code in the answer. In the "To" field added the email that you get from the `<form>` and some validation code for the email.